# How to apply PIXI.js v5 BulgePinchFilter

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm new to PIXI.js and I would like to use one of the provided filters (BulgePinchFilter) from `@pixi/filter-filters`.
If I'm correct i can apply these filters to any `DisplayObject`, but in my example it doesn't work.

**index.html**

```
<main>
    <div id="myCanvas"></div>
</main>
```

And here is the `app.js` file i wrote

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";
import { BulgePinchFilter } from 'pixi-filters';
import {Container} from 'pixi.js';


    let app = new PIXI.Application({width: 200, height: 200, transparent:true }),
          container = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    container.appendChild(app.view);

    const texture = new PIXI.Texture.from(image);
    const bg = PIXI.Sprite.from(texture);
    let appContainer = new Container();

    bg.width = app.screen.width ;
    bg.height = app.screen.height ;

    let x = 40,
        y = 40;

    const myFilter = new BulgePinchFilter([x,y], 20, 0.5);

    appContainer.filters = [ new BulgePinchFilter([app.screen.width/2 ,app.screen.height/2 ], 500, 0.5) ];

    appContainer.addChild(bg);

    app.stage.addChild(appContainer);
```

Right now I can only see the image rendered, but cannot see any *Bulge* effect on it.

Answer (score 2):

My bad. The `X` and `Y` coordinates were bad in my example.
The minimum of these coordinates are **0** and **1** is the maximum.

So if I wanted the filter on the center:

```
let x = 0.5,
    y = 0.5;

const myFilter = new BulgePinchFilter([x,y], 20, 0.5);
```